# Function to change page with a selected table row acting strange

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the function below to check what table row has been selected based on the change in the background colour of the row. If none have been selected then it will give a dialog box saying that there is an error. If a row is selected then it should allow you to go to the edit page when you click the button. For some reason this only works about half the time and shows the error box even when a row is selected. Any help with this would be appreciated

```
$('#edit').click(function() {
                var selected =  $('#deliverytable').find('tr').css("background-color");

                if(selected == "rgb(187, 187, 187)"){
                    window.location = 'editd.html';
                }else{
                    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                        .html('<p>Please select a table row</p>')
                        .dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            title: 'ERROR'
                        });
                    $dialog.dialog('open');
                }
            });
```

Comment: is there only one raw in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on style property to determine an UI state is plain bad practice. Consider `addClass('ui-row-selected')` for example then easy check with `hasClass('ui-row-selected')` or `is('.ui-row-selected')`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's CSS method will only return "the value of a style property for the FIRST element in the set of matched elements." - http://api.jquery.com/css/.  Therefore this line of code isn't doing as you expect.

```
$('#deliverytable').find('tr').css("background-color");
```

This is only returning the `background-color` of only the first row in the table.  Therefore your logic is only checking that row.  If you want to check all rows you'll have to do this logic in a loop.

```
$('#deliverytable').find('tr').each(function(index, row) {
    if ($(row).css('backgroundColor') == "rgb(187, 187, 187)") {
        //Change the window location
    } else {
        //Show the dialog
    }
});
```